# If $x\leq a$, does it mean that there should be at least one $x$ which is equal to $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, real-numbers

When we say $x<a$, it means $x$ is strictly less than $a$. If $x\leq a$, does it mean that there should be at least one $x$ which is equal to $a$? If there is no any $x$ which is equal to $a$, then can we write $x\leq a$ (because it is read as "less than or equal to")?

Comment: Less *should be*, more *might be*

Answer (score 3):

No, not necessarily. If we can write that $x<a$, we also write that $x\le a$ because $\le$ contains two possibilities: either $x<a$ or $x=a$. Of course, it is more precise to write $x<a$ if $x$ cannot be equal to $a$, but it is not a mistake to write $x\le a$.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of confusion here. You are talking about real numbers. The expression $x \leq a$ means that $x$ belongs to the set
$$A_{\leq} := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon x \leq a \}$$

That means $x$ *can* have the value $a$ or anything less. If you find an $x > a$ then $x \notin A_{leq}$.  If you consider $x < a$ then the number $x=a$ *does not* belong to the set
$$A_{<} := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon x < a \}$$

The expression $x \leq a$ just means that we *allow* $x$ to be equal to $a$ but there is no reason to assume that unless you can also show that $x \geq a$ which then would imply $x=a$

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confused. The expression $$x\leq a$$ means that the particular $x$ we are talking about is either smaller than or equal to $a$. So, for example, $3\leq 4$ is true, and $3\leq 3$ is also true.

---

You are speaking as if there are multiple possible options for what $x$ is, but if you want to speak about that, then you need to use **quantifiers**. So, you can make statements like

> For all $x\in A$, we know that $x\leq a$.

Notice the first two words, "for all". They mean that **whichever** $x$ from the set $A$ I select, I know that $x$ will be smaller than or equal to $A$.

**NOW**, you can legitimatelly ask about different values of $x$, and **now** we can ask "does there *need* to be some $x\in A$ for whic $x=a$? And the answer is

- **no**, there doesn't *need* to be (as, for example, you could have $A=[0,1]$ and $a=2$), but
- there *might* be (as you can also have $A=[0,1]$ and $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means there is *possibly* an $x$ that equals $a$.

The inequalities summarise what we know about the location of $x$ relative to $a$ on the number line.

If $x \le a$ then we cannot rule out the *possibility* that $x=a$.

However if $x \lt a$ then we can with certainty rule out the possibility that $x=a$.